# How to join ChargeBacks with original transaction invoice in Oracle AR query?

Tags: oracle, plsql, report, invoice, oracle-ebs

I want to join chargeback transaction to its original invoice but I cannot find a link to join in table.
Both transactions exist independently in table : ar_payment_schedules_all

I need to find a join like some transaction_id etc.

Comment: you would be better off trying to find EBS help on support.oracle.com rather than on #SO. This question is slightly unique and finding answer here is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They join through the `AR_ADJUSTMENTS_ALL` table.

Join:

```
AR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULES_ALL.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = AR_ADJUSTMENTS.CHARGEBACK_CUSTOMER_TRX_ID.
```

... to get the adjustment record(s) that associate the chargeback with the original transaction(s).  Then join:

```
AR_ADJUSTMENTS.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_ID = AR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULES_ALL.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_ID
```

... to get the payment schedule(s) of the original transaction(s).

See the DDL for the seeded view `AR_CHARGEBACKS_V` for code.